# Unable to catch thrown exception from async method in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, exception

I am unable to catch thrown exceptions from an async method in Spring. I have written an uncaught exception handler to catch but was unsuccessful.
The application will enable to start any number of forever running asynchronous jobs.
I think my async method needs to return Future so that I can store it in hashmap and check its status or stop the job. I also can get all running jobs by storing it.
I think I can't use get method of future because if the input is correct it blocks and my job will be forever running. I need to send status as started if the input is fine. Whenever an exception occurs in the Async method it is thrown but I am unable to catch it. How can I do that?
Here is my complete code.

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class Application  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

AsyncConfig.java

```
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyExecutor-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }


    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new AsyncExceptionHandler();
    }
}
```

AsyncExceptionHandler.java

```
public class AsyncExceptionHandler implements AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleUncaughtException(Throwable throwable, Method method, Object... obj) {

        System.out.println("Exception Cause - " + throwable.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Method name - " + method.getName());
        for (Object param : obj) {
            System.out.println("Parameter value - " + param);
        }
    }
}
```

createBucket.java

```
@Service
public class createBucket {
    @Async
    public Future<String> start(String config){
        try {
            JSONObject map = new JSONObject(config);
            Jedis jedis = new Jedis(map.getString("jedisip"));
            jedis.auth(map.getString("password"));
            // code to make a kafka consumer subscribe to a topic given in config input
            while(true) {
                //forever running code which polls using a kafka consumer
            }
        }
        catch(JedisException j) {
            throw new JedisException("Some msg");
        }
    }
}
```

Endpoint.java

```
@Controller
public class Endpoint {
    @Autowired
    private createBucket service;

    private Future<String> out;
    private HashMap<String, Future<String>> maps = new HashMap<>();

    @PostMapping(value = "/start", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String> starttask(@RequestBody String conf) {
        try {
        out = service.start(conf);
        maps.put(conf, out);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("exception", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
        return new ResponseEntity<>("{\"started\":\"true\"}", HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @Deadpool sorry, I have updated the question. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in official doc, AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler is used for void return value.
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#spring-integration

In your scenario, I recommend using CompletableFuture and DeferredResult:

```
    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<String> start(String config) {
        CompletableFuture completableFuture = new CompletableFuture();
        try {
            JSONObject map = new JSONObject(config);
            Jedis jedis = new Jedis(map.getString("jedisip"));
            jedis.auth(map.getString("password"));
            completableFuture.complete("started!");
        }
        catch(JedisException j) {
            completableFuture.completeExceptionally(j);
        }

        return completableFuture;
    }
```

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/start", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity> starttask(@RequestBody String conf) {

        CompletableFuture<String> start = service.start(conf);

        DeferredResult<ResponseEntity> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();

        start.whenComplete((res, ex) -> {
            if (ex == null) {
                ResponseEntity<String> successEntity = new ResponseEntity<>("{\"started\":\"true\"}", HttpStatus.CREATED);\
                deferredResult.setResult(successEntity);
            } else {
                // handle ex here!
                ResponseEntity<String> exEntity = new ResponseEntity<>("exception", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                deferredResult.setResult(exEntity);
            }
        });

        return deferredResult;

    }
```

There is another serious problem. The following code is not thread safe.

```
private Future<String> out;
private HashMap<String, Future<String>> maps = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: if you dont need these codes, just delete them. otherwise you shuold use immutable field and concurrent collections.

Comment: How exactly does this work? Will this run in the background and allow the user to navigate to another page? Otherwise why is the result being differed if the user will have navigated to another page? I do not want the user to wait.